# not able to open Jenkins portal

Tags: azure, jenkins

I have created an Ubuntu virtual machine in Microsoft azure. I have installed docker on it and ran the Jenkins image through docker.

```
mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home 
chown -R 1000:1000 /var/jenkins_home/ 
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -d --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

The container is running successfully but I am not able to access it in the browser.

**link: http://publicip:8080**

Comment: What's are the outputs of `docker container ps` and `docker container logs ${container_id}`? What message is shown when you try to access it?

Comment: The container is running successfully and below are the container logs. I am able to open the Jenkins portal inside the VM but not outside the VM.


INFO jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onAttained: Completed initialization
INFO hudson.WebAppMain$3#run: Jenkins is fully up and running
INFO h.m.DownloadService$Downloadable#load: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
INFO hudson.util.Retrier#start: Performed the action check updates server successfully at the attempt #1
INFO hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork#lambda$doRun$0: Finished Download metadata. 13,870 ms

Answer (score 0):

I have added an inbound rule to allow port:8080 and now I am able to open the Jenkins portal outside the host machine.